# email and password cann't retain when encrypted data using sharedPreferences

Tags: android

I am using AESHelper to create encrypt and decrypt .Email and password can encrypt and decrypt.But,when I decrypt the encrypted data,cann't save email and password when I reopened the application.I am using sharedpreferences to save email and password.I passed encrypted data from login button event function.How can I do that?Please help.Sorry for my stupid question.

**Here is piece of my code**

```
    private void loadSavedPreferences() {
        try {

            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

             String name = sharedPreferences.getString("storedName","");
             String pass = sharedPreferences.getString("storedPass","");

             String decrypted_username = AESHelper.decrypt(keyvalue, name);
             String decrypted_password = AESHelper.decrypt(keyvalue, pass);
             Log.v("EncryptDecrypt", "Decoded String username " + decrypted_username);
             Log.v("EncryptDecrypt", "Decoded String password" + decrypted_password);
             mEmailView.setText(decrypted_username);
             mPasswordView.setText(decrypted_password);

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            // Log.v("EncryptDecrypt", "Decoded String "+e.getMessage() );
        }

 private void savePreferences(String key, String value) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();

    }
```

Comment: Where are you saving them? Can you post that code too?

Comment: You may be missing `commit` after adding values to `preferences`